# XtraGrid(DevExpress) Comparing Date Installed column and Date Expired column in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid

I just want to ask if it is possible to comparing an xtragrid gridView1.Columns("DateInstalled") and Date.today?

this is my code and it won't work for me:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCellStyle(sender As Object, e As Views.Grid.RowCellStyleEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCellStyle
        Dim dateExp As Date = Date.Parse(GridView1.Columns("DateExpired"))

        If dateExp < Date.Today Then
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub
```

The output is, if the Date.Today greater than column("DateExpired"), it will fill the entire row with highlighted represent that it is expired.

Sincerely,

Comment: How does it make sense to parse the `Visible` property of a column to a `Date`? I don't know exactly how that control works but it should be obvious that you need to get a value from a cell somehow. My guess would be that that `e` parameter provides you the means to determine which row is currently being styled so you would need to get the appropriate cell from that row and the value from that cell.

Comment: @jmcilhinney
I removed the visible, for am I beginner for this matter, I don't know what is the exact syntax.

Comment: Did you look at what members the `e` parameter has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
   Private Sub GridView1_RowCellStyle(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellStyleEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCellStyle

        Dim dateExp As Date = Date.Parse(GridView1.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "DateExpired"))

        If dateExp < Date.Today Then
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If

    End Sub
```